# maven version tag [1.0,) does not work

Tags: java, maven

I have the following dependency defined in my `pom.xml`

```
   <dependency>
         <groupId>runtime_shared</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.boofcv</artifactId>
         <version>[1.0,)</version>
   </dependency>
```

with which I wanted to say "Take all the jars starting from version 1.0". [I guess this is the correct way](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html).

I have two versions in my local repository (.`m2/repository`) and I need both of these jars to have a successful compilation. However, I get an error saying that some packages do not exist. I checked the debug output and saw that maven only considers one of the jars (the last version) during the compilation, disregards the other one. And when I looked at the error message closely, I noticed that the packages it is talking about, are in the jar which is disregarded.

```
[DEBUG]  /home/user/.m2/repository/runtime_shared/org.boofcv/1.0.2/org.boofcv-1.0.2.jar
```

Does anyone know why isn't version tag working?

Comment: You have to use one concreate Version. You can not use a range as dependency

Comment: Then why does it have [such](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) an attribute?

Comment: this is for enforcer plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a syntax unique to the maven `enforcer` plugin.

Such syntax like `[1.0,)` is not valid for normal use of maven projects.

As per Jens' comment, you should specify a concrete version.

Here is the [plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: So if I want to use multiple versions with range specification such as given in my question, I should go for the `enforcer` plugin to make it work.  Thanks. I will include the basic form of the plugin in my `pom.xml` to make the tag functional.